# Problema al crear una columna de un dataframe utilizando una función

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

He creado una función a la que paso el año, mes, día, hora, minutos, longitud y latitud y me calcula diferentes valores relacionados con la posición del sol. Casi todos los cálculos son de trigonometría, por lo que me toca usar una función que me calcula un ángulo a partir de la tangente. Para ello uso la función de numpy [`np.arctan2( dY1, dX1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html?highlight=arctan2#numpy.arctan2). Esta fución devuelve un ángulo entre pi y -pi y yo necesito el valor entre 0 y 2pi para otros cáculos, por ello he creado un condicional dentro de la función de tal manera que si el ángulo es negativo le sume 2pi:

```
dY1 = cos( sunpos.EObl ) * sin( sunpos.ELong )
dX1 = cos( sunpos.ELong )
    
if dY1 < 0:
        RightAscension = arctan2( dY1, dX1) + 2*pi
else:
        RightAscension = arctan2( dY1, dX1)
```

Si llamo a la función con con unos valores concretos funciona perfectamente, pero si intento utilizar esta funcion para crear una columna nueva de un dataframe el condicional me produce un error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10116/71367177.py in <module>
      8 # dir(sunpos)
      9 
---> 10 Hibrido["Azimuth"]=sunpos(Hibrido["Year"],Hibrido["Month"],Hibrido["Dia"],Hibrido["Hour"],Hibrido["Minute"],Lat,Long).get('Azimuth')
     11 
     12 
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10116/2460032985.py in sunpos(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Lat, Long)
     40 
     41 
---> 42     if dY1 < 0:
     43         RightAscension = arctan2( dY1, dX1) + 2*pi
     44     else:

D:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Por lo que me ha parecido entender al hacer pruebas, cuando se crea la nueva columna no ejecuta la función fila a fila, sino que la va ejecutando con todas las filas en paralelo y cuando llega al condicional se encuentra con que hay un montón de `RightAscension` que tiene que comparar con cero.

Se me ocurren dos posibles soluciones, pero no logro implementar ninguna. La primera es buscar la forma de que numpy me de los resultados ya entre 0 y 2pi y quitar el condicional de la función. La segunda es hacer que el condicional se ejecute para el valor de `RightAscension` de cada fila. No he sabido hacer ninguna

El problema equivalente al mio simplificado sería el siguiente. Tengo un df con dos columnas con valores en el eje X e Y y quiero saber que ángulo forman mediante una función. Como necesito que me lo devuelva entre 0 y 2pi, a los ángulos negativos les sumo 2pi para saber su equivalente (por ejemplo, -90 grados equivale a 270 grados)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,-1,-1,1],
                'y':[1,1,-1,-1]})

def atan(x,y):
    
    atan=np.arctan2(y,x)
    if atan<0:
        atan=atan+2*np.pi
    return atan
    
df['atan']= atan(df['x'],df['y'])
    
print(df['atan'])
```

El valor obtenido para este caso sería una columna con los valores  0.785398 , 2.356194,  3.926991 y 5.497787. Sin embargo se produce el siguiente error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10116/848756074.py in <module>
    14     return atan
    15 
---> 16 df['atan']= atan(df['x'],df['y'])
    17 
    18 print(df['atan'])

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10116/848756074.py in atan(x, y)
     9     atan=np.arctan2(y,x)
    10 
---> 11     if atan<0:
    12         atan=atan+2*np.pi
    13 

D:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
  1535     @final
  1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
  1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
  1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y el míninimo código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Ademas de lo que dice HeytalePazguato, te diria que lo de sumarle 2pi solo te va a llevar a un resultado erroneo. Si queres que el numero este entre pi y 2pi probablemente deban sumar pi en todos los casos.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias por tu comentario. He añadido un ejemplo similar que me puede ayudar

Comment: @DanteS. Igual no me expliqué bien. La función de np te devuelve un ángulo entre -pi y pi, es decir, que en vez de darme un ángulo de 270º me devuelve -90º. Como a mi me interesa que sea un ángulo entre 0 y 360º, a esos -90 le sumo 360 para obtener los 270. Logicamente, a los valores entre 0 y 180 no les tengo que sumar nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que en el `if` estás intentando comparar una `array` con `< 0` y por eso devuelve el error:

Si deseas obtener los valores negativos de una serie y únicamente trabajar con ellos entonces podrías hacer:

```
atan[atan < 0] += 2*np.pi
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,-1,-1,1],
                'y':[1,1,-1,-1]})

def atan(x,y):
    atan=np.arctan2(y,x)
    atan[atan < 0] += 2*np.pi
    return atan
    
df['atan'] = atan(df['x'],df['y'])
    
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
   x  y      atan
0  1  1  0.785398
1 -1  1  2.356194
2 -1 -1  3.926991
3  1 -1  5.497787
```

Otra opción, que se integraría mejor con `pandas` es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) y aplicar la función a cada fila del `dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,-1,-1,1],
                'y':[1,1,-1,-1]})

def atan(row):
    atan = np.arctan2(row['y'], row['x'])
    if atan < 0:
        atan += 2 * np.pi
    return atan
    
df['atan'] = df.apply(atan, axis=1)
print(df)
```

En este caso `atan` se puede evaluar como lo habías considerado ya que es un número y no un `array` ya que se evalua fila por fila.

Esto devuelve:

```
   x  y      atan
0  1  1  0.785398
1 -1  1  2.356194
2 -1 -1  3.926991
3  1 -1  5.497787
```

Ahora, en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución utilizando `timeit`:

La opción utilizando `apply` (Segundo ejemplo):

```
1.6 ms ± 47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

La opción utilizando directamente `atan` en todo el `dataframe` (Primer ejemplo):

```
2.58 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Como podemos ver, la opción utilizando `apply` es más eficiente.

Como recomendación general, procura siempre utilizar los métodos de `pandas` para trabajar con los `dataframes` ya que han sido optimizados y además se ejecutan directamente en el código de `pandas` escrito en `C` que se procesa más rápido que `python`, en especial al trabajar con listas/arreglos y `dataframes`.

Comment: muchas gracias! creo que así voy a poder solucionar mi error. Y gracias también por ayudarme a "preguntar" mejor por aquí.